# IE8 Screen Resize Called on jQuery Toggle

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, resize

I'm having some issues with IE8 (imagine that...) when I'm calling a function on screen resize.  This function that I am calling is a set of responsive tweaks designed to make my site more usable on mobile devices.  I call the function on page load and after the screen has been resized.  The issue I'm experiencing occurs when I use jQuery to toggle something on the scree, such as a search box.  According to IE8, each time I toggle something, it triggers the screen resize function and then which then hides the stuff I just toggled.

I created a gist with some sample code because pastebin and IE8 don't seem to work together.
https://gist.github.com/johns996/5501932

Comment: You should post your code here, not in a gist

Comment: stack ripped out the doctype and header section when I tried to paste it in.  this is why I chose a gist.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem using IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/yJxG9/6/embedded/result/   Because in emulated mode, i cannot.

Comment: That fiddle when loaded on IE8 will produce the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution for your problem, just check if the resize did really resize your window:

```
//run the tweaks on page resize
var x,y;
var w=$(window).resize(function() {
    var newx=w.width(); 
    var newy=w.height();
    if(x!=newx || y!=newy){
        // run code...
    }
    x=newx; y=newy;
});
```

Just tested it in IE8 and works.

Comment: Perfect. I knew there had to be an easy way to do this, I just didn't think of actually checking the window size.

Comment: As a side note, I pulled out the height check in the version of the above script that I used because the window's height seemed to be changing when I toggled the box causing it to hide again.

Comment: I have seen IE8 do weirder stuff! ;-) Does the page get horizontal scrollbars when you toggle? That could be the reason for a height change.

Comment: I didn't see any scrollbars appear but I didn't test it that extensively.  My responsive scripts are only concerned about the width of the page so your fix was more than adequate for that.